# Can we access controller method inside factory AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

I have this method inside one controller and I want to access it inside factory I already injected `$scope` variable in factory through function, I am getting all the values from scope except this method which is defined in that controller any help appreciated.

```
.factory('viewPdfDocument',['$sce','searchService', 'scrollTop', 'pdfPluginDetector', '$timeout',function($sce, searchService, scrollTop, pdfPluginDetector, $timeout) {
    return {
        pdfView: function ($scope, docId, pdftest, accessForbiddenMessage, genericErrorMessage) {
            clearCheckBoxes();
        }
    };
}]);
```

Comment: Why you want to do that,If there is something that need to shared accross use common service for bth

Comment: Thanks for fast reply Riyaj.  the thing is that there is one method i want to use that on multiple controller so i defined that method inside the factory. but that method contains some other method call on same controller.

Comment: Friend ,You doing something wrong.You should separate the things.Return the value from factory in controller and on that basis call our metod

Answer (score 1):

The service should not need to know about the detail of the controller. You should be able to re-use your service in other situations where perhaps that callback to the controller is different.

If it is a single-shot callback, say to indicate completion of some activity, then the cleanest way is to make the service method return a promise and resolve it when it wants to notify the controller. Then back in the controller you act on the completion of the promise

Controller:

```
 viewPdfDocument.pdfView(...).then(clearCheckBoxes);
```

This gives maximum flexibility for the controller, it call `.then()` as often as it wants with different functions.

There is also scope for promises to give ongoing notifications, say to display a progresss bar as something downloads.

```
 viewPdfDocument.pdfView(...).then(null, null, updateProgress);
```

Note that if you want to use progress notifications in angular you have to use the old `$q.defer()` mechanism to create and notify the promise, otherwise use the ES6 compatible mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a notify function in your service and in your controler you will add the function.

The controller

```
//In your controller:

var clearCheckBoxes = function(){
//your function here
}

viewPdfDocument.registerObserverCallback(clearCheckBoxes);
```

The Service:

```
//In your service:
.factory('viewPdfDocument',['$sce','searchService', 'scrollTop', 'pdfPluginDetector', '$timeout',function($sce, searchService, scrollTop, pdfPluginDetector, $timeout) {
var observerCallbacks = [];
var notifyObservers = function () {
            angular.forEach(observerCallbacks, function (callback) {
                callback();
            });
        };
    return {
             observerCallbacks: function (callback) {
                observerCallbacks.push(callback);
            },
            pdfView: function () {
    notifyObservers();
}

}])
```

It's called Observer pattern.
You can use it if you want to notify several functions in  controllers from the service