# Can I access method defined in controller like $rootscope.method() inside factory?

Tags: angularjs

How to access the controller method inside factory.

```
        //controller.js
        $rootScope.stackTraceReport = function(error){
            var exception = errorHandler(error);
            //reproting to server
            StackTrace.report(exception,serviceUrl);
        }

      // factory.js
     .factory('viewPdfFailure',['scrollTop', '$timeout', function(scrollTop, $timeout) {
    return {
        viewError: function ($scope, $rootScope, data, status, headers, config, accessForbiddenMessage, genericErrorMessage) {
            $timeout(function () {
                $scope.errorMessages = [];
                $scope.infoMessages = [];
            }, 7000);
            console.error('Error in viewDocument, status: ' + status);
            if (status == 403) {
                $scope.errorMessages.push(accessForbiddenMessage);
                scrollTop.onErrorScrollTop('id-header');
            } else {
                $scope.errorMessages.push(genericErrorMessage);
                scrollTop.onErrorScrollTop('id-header');
            }
            $rootScope.stackTraceReport(data);
        }
```

Help me figure out how can I access this controller method inside the factory. I am getting the *method not defined error*. Do I need to inject the controller inside the factory?

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35357312/can-we-access-controller-method-inside-factory-angularjs)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are facing this error because when you call the `$rootScope.stackTraceReport(data);` method you dont defined it (calling the  `$rootScope.stackTraceReport = function(error){...}`).

Make sure the function definition is called first (you can put two `console.log` to see witch is called first.

But I think its better you create a singleton Util factory to make all this "globals" functions is the same file and make sure the function is defined when you call it. (http://blog.jdriven.com/2013/03/how-to-create-singleton-angularjs-services-in-4-different-ways/)

Answer (score 0):

The method should be defined in the `run` method so as to consume it elsewhere:

Code:

```
.run(['$rootScope', 'StackTrace', function ($rootScope, StackTrace) {
    $rootScope.stackTraceReport = function (error) {
        var exception = errorHandler(error);
        //reproting to server
        StackTrace.report(exception, serviceUrl);
    }
}]);
```